# repalce the param /params value of multiple hrefs with single value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple links with hrefs with param `'selectedstudentid'` appended as shown here; currently I am populating these links using jQuery as shown below:

```
 $(".button1").click(function() {
 $(".add_group").each(function(){
                  $(this).attr("href",($(this).attr("href") +'?selectedstudentid='+selectedstudentid));
                   });
});

a href="/students/6691/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70007" class="add_group" id="add_group_6691"


a href="/students/6692/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70007" class="add_group" id="add_group_6692"


a href="/students/6693/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70007" class="add_group" id="add_group_6693"
```

I require to change the value of `'selectedstudentid'` upon click of a button everytime using jQuery, but it is currently appending the href value with multiple id's ex:
`href="/students/6692/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70007?selectedstudentid=70009?"`, I do not want this

I require it to appear as shown below:

```
a href="/students/6691/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70009" class="add_group" id="add_group_6691"


a href="/students/6692/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70009" class="add_group" id="add_group_6692"


a href="/students/6693/movestudenttonewgroup?selectedstudentid=70009" class="add_group" id="add_group_6693"
```

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, Use regexp

```
this.href = this.href.replace(/selectedstudentid=\d*/g, "selectedstudentid="+ selectedstudentid);
```

with your code

```
    var new_href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/selectedstudentid=\d*/g, "selectedstudentid="+ selectedstudentid);
    $(this).attr("href", new_href);
```

Comment: I have added the  following logic and it worked for me. Firstly I am checking if the href value has the parameter "selectedstudentid", if it exists I am removing that parameter using the split function and then appending the new value for selectedstudentid param

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following logic and it worked perfectly fine for me. Firstly I am checking if the href value has the parameter "selectedstudentid". If it exists I am removing that parameter using the split function and then appending the new value for selectedstudentid param

```
         $(".add_group").each(function(){
                var old_href =  $(this).attr("href");
                if(old_href.toString().indexOf("selectedstudentid") != -1){
                      var arr = $(this).attr("href").toString().split('?');
                      $(this).attr("href", arr[0]+'?selectedstudentid='+selectedstudent);
                    }

                else{
                   $(this).attr("href",($(this).attr("href") +'?selectedstudentid='+selectedstudent));
                }
              });
```

Comment: `attr()` returns a string already (attributes *are* strings); there's no need to call `toString()`.